# Bash lost variables after function

Tags: bash, shell

I've a simple Bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

function askExp
(
    read -ep "$1" -n "$2" -r "$3"
)
askExp "PHP? [Y/n]: " 1 php

echo $php
```

How to modify above script to work? No after `echo $php` I get nothing. I need to use bash function, because after that I'll add a regexp verification inside function. The function will be used many times in a script.

Comment: The function definition is wrong. This is invalid shell syntax.

Comment: It's valid syntax. A function body isn't limited to `{ list; }`: it can be any compound command. It's bizarre but legal to use `(list)`, `((expression))`, `[[ expression ]]`, `for`, `select`, `case`, `if`, `while`, or `until`.

Comment: Actually, it's a little wrong; you need the `()` between the function's name and the subshell body. I'm not sure if this is a bug in the parser or not, but even if it is and it were fixed, `askExp () ( ... )` would still be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell runs whatever present under `(..)` in a sub-shell and especially variables the defined lose their scope once the shell terminates. You needed to enclose the function within `{..}` which encloses a compound statement in `bash` shell to make sure the commands within are run in the *same* shell as the one invoked.

```
function askExp { read -ep "$1" -n "$2" -r "$3"; }
```

As a small experiment you can observe the output of

```
hw()(
  echo hello world from $BASHPID
)
hw 
echo $BASHPID
```

and when running from the same shell.

```
hw(){
  echo hello world from $BASHPID
}
hw 
echo $BASHPID
```

The reason is in the former case, the variable set in the shell created inside `(..)` is lost in the local shell.